# Android Studio 2.2.2 preview and design not showing properly

Tags: android-studio, ide

I have recently installed Android Studio 2.2.2. But in the IDE the preview and design window for xml not showing complete mobile-like appearance that I used to view in previous version, rather it is showing only the mobile screen with rulers around. How can I see full featured preview/design? Pls advice. 
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for this, But its new functionally it will look like this by default. only screen and blueprints, No mobile.

https://developer.android.com/studio/write/layout-editor.html